# Need Google OAuth 2.0 Architecture Suggestion for Sending Smtp Mails via java mail Api

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, jakarta-mail

We have a Client Server Based Java Product, I need to integrate google OAuth in server dashboard where our client can sign in and allow access to gmail API. After that, server will use REFRESH TOKEN and ACCESS TOKEN to send Email reports to some emails Ids using client gmail Via Java Mail API.
We need to implement sign in only once and send mails forever i.e. Offline Access (Means REFRESH TOKEN is compulsory).
Our product is deployed as in premise as well as cloud based (At a time only one). Thus in client environment we can have private ip or public ip or public ip mapped to dns.

I know there are two way in which this can be done:

1) server side authentication

2) client side authentication

In Both cases you need public dns mapped REDIRECT URI ie a url where google will redirect the user after sign in. But in our case, we dont have
always a public domain mapped to client server machine. Also we cannot provide localhost in redirect uri as well.

SO

PROBLEM I: What should be used in place of REDIRECT_URI

PROBLEM II: We have many clients so should we use one application for each client or we should deploy a single application on cloud, where each client dashboard will be redirected while sign in and in response we will get token.

Any other alternatives for above problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the architecture.
Google apps give the flexibility to add multiple java script origins and redirect uri's.
So we need to create only one app in developer console. For each client, we will add a authorized java script origin and redirect uri in google app online. And when sign in button will be pressed in client's server we will give redirect uri accoring to that client which is already added in google app. For private ip there is no solution, but localhost can be used with the restriction to sign in from browser on server system.